# Grafico de linhas com meses no eixo x no ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, plot

Estou fazendo aulas de R e surgiu um exercício para fazer um gráfico de linhas no `ggplot2` com os dados de atrasos de vôos por aeroporto. 
No eixo X deveriam ficar os meses (que estão em números), mas quando ploto, ele mostra intervalos de 2,5 (O gráfico acaba mostrando até o mês 12,5!).

Já tentei transformando os meses em factors e mesmo assim continua mostrando em 2,5. Não encontrei no help o uso do "breaks".

Alguém tem ideia de qual o problema e como resolver?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
voo <- flights

voo %>% group_by(month, origin) %>% 
  summarize(media_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = media_delay, group = origin, col = origin))
```

Comment: Testei aqui `voo$month <- as.factor(voo$month)` antes de plotar e deu certo.

Comment: William, obrigado pela ajuda! Eu havia usado `factor(voo$month)`. Ele retorna no console as entradas e os levels mas não transforma em _factors_ (eu não sabia).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O central no `ggplot` são sempre os seus dados. Seus dados estão em um formato numérico e, por isso, o `ggplot` acredita ser melhor usar uma escala contínua em X e fazer a divisão de tal forma que os intervalos que apareçam sejam de`2.5` em `2.5`.

Há várias formas de corrigir isso:

1. Explicitar o intervalo que você deseja mantendo a escala contínua;
2. Transformar os dados em categóricos para forçar que todos os dados apareçam;
3. Transformar os dados em data para usar a escala de data no gráfico.

A opção 2 não será mostrada porque é um opção que, embora possa resolver algum problema específico, também pode incluir novos problemas (como a forma de ordenar os valores, etc) e não corresponde a uma representação adequada da variável.

### 1. Intervalos da escala numérica

Para fazer isso basta incluir as quebras desejadas na escala numérica com o argumentos `breaks` da função `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
voo %>% group_by(month, origin) %>% 
  summarize(media_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = media_delay, group = origin, col = origin)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ver mais sobre escalas no `ggplot`, veja esse [link](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html)

### 2. Escala de tempo

Nesse caso, nem precisaremos definir a escala, mas alterar a variável e confiar nos padrões do `ggplot`. Para isso basta transformar a coluna `month` numa variável de tipo `date` manter o mesmo comando da pergunta para criar o gráfico.

```
voo %>% 
  # Adiciona zeros a esquerda 
  mutate(month = formatC(month, width = 2, flag = "0"),
         day = formatC(day, width = 2, flag = "0"),
         month = lubridate::ymd(paste0(year, month, day)),
         month = lubridate::floor_date(month, "month")) %>% 
  group_by(month, origin) %>% 
  summarize(media_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = media_delay, group = origin, col = origin))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De todo modo, recomendo sempre alterar a variável para data nesse tipo de caso.

Comment: Maravilha Tomas! essas soluções não foram abordadas no curso (ainda) mas são certeiras! só poderia me explicar pq adicionar zeros a esquerda e pq usar o paste0 em vez do paste? Muito Obrigado

Comment: Fiz a resposta meio na pressa, mas a versão curta é que o formato da data espera datas como `01032019` para primeiro de março de 2019, e como os dias e meses estavam inteiros, eles ficaria `132019`. O `paste0` cola textos sem espaços entre eles.

Comment: Só uma dica: não precisa confiar nos padrões do ggplot pra escala de tempo. Pode usar `scale_x_date()` para personalizar.

Comment: Claro! O objetivo foi simplificar a resposta.